# Convert richtext to plaintext using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, richtext

I have the following richtext (from flex) that I need to covert to plain text and export this to excel.  Although html can be exported to excel, the problem is, for bulleted list, it's trying to merged 2 column cells... and for paragraphs, it's merging multiple rows.

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Hello</FONT></P>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><LI><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"><B><I><U>Working</U></I></B></FONT></LI></TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><LI><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"><B><I><U>numbers</U></I></B></FONT></LI></TEXTFORMAT>
```

I need it to be just plain text, if possible retaining the line space and some formatting like bold when i export to excel so the whole thing fits in inside one cell.  This is how it looks like in html:

Hello

***Working***

***numbers***

I tried replacing it with regex but it doesn't work.  Please advise.

Comment: Insert into an element (div?) and get the [*textContent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent).

Comment: i did that but nothing happens, it returns blank

Comment: i need to convert it without the browser

Comment: You need a parser. If you can't use a browser's built–in parser, or say the [*DOMParser*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), you'll need to parse it yourself (BTW, there's a missing closing *textformat* tag, but that's not the problem).

Comment: Please Refer to this Stack Overflow [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403678/converting-from-rich-text-format-to-plain-text-problems)