# Convert RTF to and from plain text

Tags: javascript, rtf

I have a requirement to convert plain text to and from RTF (RichText Format) using javascript.

I am looking for a function for each conversion, and I am not looking to use a library.

**Conversion from plain to RTF**

The formatting styles and colours are not important, all that matters is that the plain text i converted into a **valid** RTF format

**Conversion from RTF to plain**

Again, the styles are not important. They can be completed removed. All that is required is that **all** text data remains (no loss of entered data)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I [found a c# answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542417/838807) which was a good starting point, but I needed a Javascript solution.

There is no guarantee that these are 100% reliable, but they seem to work well with the data I have tested on.

```
function convertToRtf(plain) {
    plain = plain.replace(/\n/g, "\\par\n");
    return "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang2057{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\f0\\fs17 " + plain + "\\par\n}";
}

function convertToPlain(rtf) {
    rtf = rtf.replace(/\\par[d]?/g, "");
    return rtf.replace(/\{\*?\\[^{}]+}|[{}]|\\\n?[A-Za-z]+\n?(?:-?\d+)?[ ]?/g, "").trim();
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nu86fco4/) of them both in action

Comment: or [here](https://github.com/lazygyu/RTF-parser) you've got a javascript RTF parser by lazygyu

Comment: I would give you 100 upvotes for this if I could, thank you!

Comment: This won’t work well for Unicode input (non-English chars, typographic quotation marks, etc).

Comment: @mirabilos: Yeah I would have expected there would be problems with things like that. Unfortunately I don't know enough about RTF format to provide anything more robust

Comment: rtf.replace(/\\'[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}/g, "").trim(); will remove some of the unwanted unicode characters

Comment: @TjadClark those Unicode characters are **wanted** and **needed** to be correctly represented in the output

Comment: I suppose it depends from app to app, that was just a general expression for unicode hex. My application seems to permit me to ignoring that. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Musefan's answer for some hex characters

```
function convertToPlain(rtf) {
    rtf = rtf.replace(/\\par[d]?/g, "");
    rtf = rtf.replace(/\{\*?\\[^{}]+}|[{}]|\\\n?[A-Za-z]+\n?(?:-?\d+)?[ ]?/g, "")
    return rtf.replace(/\\'[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}/g, "").trim();
}
```