# Paragraphs not maintained when saving text from RichTextBox in txt format

Tags: c#, richtextbox

The text editor I am working on properly saves its contents when saving to RTF format. However if I save to (plain)txt, html, dvc and other (plain)txt based formats all paragraphs are gone. For example:

This is the first paragraph

This is the second paragraph

This is the third paragraph

Becomes:

This is the first paragraphThis is the second paragraphThis is the third paragraph

If I use SendKeys and System.Diagnostics.Process.Start to send the RichTextBox contents to Notepad, paragraphs are maintained.
So the problem appears to be in the Save/Save as Menu code. I'm adding the code of the Save As menu.

```
 private void SaveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog1.Title = "RTE - Save File";
            SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "rtf";
            SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Rich Text Files|*.rtf|Text Files|*.txt|XML Files|*.xml|INI Files|*.ini|DVC Files|*.dvc|CSV Files |*.csv |CS Files |*.cs |HTML Files|*.html|HTML Files|*.htm|All Files|*.*";
            SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

            if (SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                if (SaveFileDialog1.FileName == "")
                {
                    return;
                }

                string strExt;
                strExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(SaveFileDialog1.FileName);
                strExt = strExt.ToUpper();

                if (strExt == ".RTF")
                {
                    rtbDoc.SaveFile(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.IO.StreamWriter txtWriter;
                    txtWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName);
                    txtWriter.Write(rtbDoc.Text);
                    txtWriter.Close();
                    txtWriter = null;
                    rtbDoc.SelectionStart = 0;
                    rtbDoc.SelectionLength = 0;
                }

                currentFile = SaveFileDialog1.FileName;
                rtbDoc.Modified = false;
                this.Text = "Editor: " + currentFile.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(currentFile.ToString() + " saved.", "File Save");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
        }
    }

    private void ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rtbDoc.Modified == true)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult answer;
                answer = MessageBox.Show("Save file?", "Document not saved", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (answer == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    return;
                }

                else if (answer == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    rtbDoc.Modified = false;
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rtbDoc.Modified = false;
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: RTF stores not in plain text, it had special tags to preserve the formatting, while txt dont have such feature. it only saves text.. try to open RTF in notepad..

Comment: You are right but still, saving as plaintext should maintain paragraphs.
Creating any kind of document in notepad for instance and then saving it won't remove the paragraphs.

Comment: i believe the issue lies on `txtWriter.Write(rtbDoc.Text);` as i think it pops out a plain text without new line characters, while the RTF output had a bunch of tags to define the paragraph. you might want to output RTF first, then convert it to plain text. perhaps [this QA on converting RTF to plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29922772/4648586) may help.

Comment: Thank you! You got me on the right track. This turned out simpler than I thought. You are right I got rid of txtWriter entirely and only had to add this in the "else" section: RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);